# How to fix error in node.js with react native WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express

I am getting this error after fetching data from my backend.
I'm trying to pass url parameters from frontend and my backend can receive it and fetch the data aslong as it matches the regular expression but somehow i don't think my url is working configured properly.
react native code

```js
const response = await fetch(
  `http://192.168.100.133:5000/api/productData/?searchTerm=${searchText}&site=${site}`,
);
const data = await response.json(); //error occurs here
```

node.js code

```js
app.get(
  `/^\/api\/productData\/\?searchTerm=\w+&site=\w+/`,
  async (req, res) => {
    // other code...
  },
);
```

NOTE: Everything was working fine before I changed the server url to use regex, but if any additional code or information is required let me know.
I'm not sure if the error is being throw because regex is not correct, If there's any mistake in the code PLEASE help me correct it. Thanks!

Comment: [RegExp literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#literal_notation_and_constructor) should not be wrapped in quotes of any kind. Remove the `\`` characters from around your route path

Comment: First, [query strings cannot be matched in route paths](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths). Second, your request URL is missing the `?` to delineate the query string. This really seems overly complicated. Just use a regular route (eg `app.get('/api/productData', ...`) and validate the `req.query` values if necessary

Comment: hey thanks a lot I'm still a rookie so this helped alot!